# glxMakeCurrent giving Segmentation Fault

Tags: glx

what could be the reasons of **glXMakeCurrent** giving **segmentation** fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are myriad reasons, most of them implementation bugs tickled by bad input.

If you want help to solve this you would need to provide as a start:

- The platform you're running on
- The libGL driver you're linking to, and what GPU, if any, is backing it
- The smallest complete code sample you can create that trigger the problem